# selecting specific subelement node trees for output using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have some XML that has an extra element and I want it gone. Input XML:

```
<top><middle><bottom><!-- other elements --><stuff/></bottom></middle></top>
```

Output desired:

```
<top><bottom><!--other elements --><stuff/></bottom></top>
```

*(note "middle" element has been snipped from the node tree)*

How do I arbitrarily snip out an element without having to create a template cascade of every possible element in the source? Is there a way to just pass all elments and subelements from a given point? including the XML tagging, attributes and content?

Searches I've done mention using `<xsl:copy>` but it doesn't work - `"node()|@*"` only returns the content and attribute value and not the actual subelement XML tree.

How do I do this in XSLT 1 or 2?  The way I am doing it now is to create a template tree for each element but the "stuff"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Identity Transform with an override for the elements you want to remove:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="middle">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: How would I change this into an element replacer instead of an element remover??? let's say I wanted to turn the "middle" tag in the example above into a "finalize" tag??

Comment: @David - `<xsl:template match="middle"><finalize><xsl:apply-templates/></finalize></xsl:template>`